# Intersection k of subsets {1,...n}

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For $k,n \in$ $\mathbb N \ \  k < n$ compute, how many ways are we able to choose $\mathbf A, \mathbf B \subseteq \{1,...n\} $ in a way, so $\lvert A \cap  B\rvert = k$

My logic here is that first, we should find the elements in the intersection k, $ {n \choose k} $. then we are left to calculate which subsets A,B are in question. To do that we can create a characteristic function that would map elements to A,B  but we need to exclude the elements that are in the intersection (k), so with the rule of multiplication the result should be $$ {n \choose k}*3^{n-k} $$

is this valid?  If so, why do we need to exclude  k elements from the mapping (characteristic) function?  This is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct answer: to count say, the pairs $(A,B)$
with $A\cap B=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ then each of $A$ and $B$ must
have $1,\ldots,k$ as elements, and for each of the remaining numbers
$k+1,\ldots,n$ either

- $j\in A$ but $j\notin B$,
- $j\in B$ but $j\notin A$ or
- $j\notin A$ and $j\notin B$.

For each of these $n-k$ numbers $j$ one has three choices, so overall
there are $3^{n-k}$ pairs $(A,B)$ with $A\cap B=\{1,\ldots,k\}$.